# updateOrCreate where date is greater than today

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to updateorcreate records in a table where the created_at date field is greater than today(midnight)?

I have the following sample:

```
Model::updateOrCreate(
          [
            'match_id' => $match->id,
            // 'created_at' => some query here to match a record created today
          ]
        );
```

Comment: Is `created_at` from input? If so, you should validate that value.

Comment: @Tpojka no it's not from input, I've commented it out. It was just illustrative of what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution I found to work:

```
Model::updateOrCreate(
          [
            'match_id' => $match->id,
            'created_at' => Model::where('created_at', '>', DB::raw('CURDATE()'))->first()->created_at ?? null
          ],
          [
            'otherColumn' => $value
          ]
        );
```

Comment: will you get results of current day too with this `where` condition?

Comment: Else you can try `Model::whereDate('created_at', '>', DB::raw('CURDATE()'))` or
`Model::whereDate('created_at', '>', date('Y-m-d'))` which should skip records of today too

Comment: Seems to be working for me so far but I like  `whereDate` instead of just `where`. Updating that. Is there any reason `CURDATE()` would not work as well as your submission?

Comment: `CURDATE() ` would surely work, I just gave an alternative to use without `DB::raw`

Comment: Tested your submission and it works as expected too (but only if I don't use `whereDate` and simply use `where` which is weird). Good alternative.

Comment: I was wondering if you will get records with `created_at` as `2018-08-04 16:49:04` for example with only `where`, hence asked :-P